# Doing the wrong list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've been trying every iteration of a list comprehension that I can in the context.

I am getting a call from a database, converting it to a list of `[['item', long integer]]`.

I want to convert the long integer to a regular one, because the rest of my math is in regular integrals.

I'm trying this:

```
catnum = c.fetchall()
catnum = [list(x) for x in catnum]
for x in catnum:
        [int(y) for y in x]
```

I've also tried x[1], and a few other things (it is always in position 1 inside the list)

No luck. How do I convert only the second value in the list to a regular integer?

Comment: post the contents of `catnum` after `catnum = c.fetchall()`

Comment: (('elated', 0L), ('depressed', 0L), ('hostile', 0L), ('agreeable', 0L), ('energetic', 0L), ('tired', 0L), ('clearheaded', 0L), ('confident', 0L), ('guilty', 0L), ('anxious', 0L), ('composed', 0L), ('confused', 0L), ('unsure', 0L))

Comment: By "integral" do you mean integer?

Comment: `[int(y) for y in x]` doesn't do anything. Well, it converts all the items in the list `x` to integers, stores them in a new list, and then *throws that list away* because you didn't say where to put it.

Comment: Any reason why you need to convert them?

Answer (score 2):

does this work?

```
catnum=[[x,int(y)] for x,y in catnum]
```

But, I think it's worth asking why you need to do this conversion.  Python should handle long integers just fine anywhere a regular integer would work.  There's a slight performance penalty to leaving them as long ints, but in most cases I don't think that would justify the extra work to convert to regular integers.

**EDIT** *for the people reading the comments, my first answer was incorrect and did not involve a list comprehension.  It relied on mutating the elements in catnum, but since those elements are in tuples, they can't be mutated.*

Comment: That's it?! I thought I had to do a list comprehension and everything.

Comment: @JakeSmith : What I had wouldn't work since you had tuples (If they were lists it would have worked).  I changed it to a list comprehension.

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- hence the "I changed it to a list comprehension"  Sorry for the confusion.  I had to change my answer because the previous version was wrong.

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- Yeah.  It's my fault.  I've added an update to the answer for people reading the comments :X

Answer (score 1):

```
[[x[0],int(x[1])] for x in catnum]
```

This will return a list of lists, where the first entry in the name and the second is the value cast down to a normal integer.